# How to change form tag information in same blade file after reloading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i have a payment page with total amount. for this have used form tag to pay as i am using 3rd party payment gateway. i want to apply promo code in payment page and show total amount with the deduction of promo amount.

so here is the pic before promo applied. i want to add new field promo amount with along with items when i click apply promo button. i am also using form tag for apply promo.

How can i change info in payment page after reloading with promo and show in same payment page.

[image]

Here is the example for payment page form tag

```
        <form action="{{ url('/pay') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
            <h3>item1    price</h3>
            <h3>item1    price</h3>
            <h3> Need to add new promo field dynamically after promo applied <h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
            
        </form>
```

This is the form tag for apply promo

```
<form  action="{{ url('/payment/applypromo') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
<input type="text" id="promocode" name="promocode" placeholder="Write Promo" style="height:40px; width:200px">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="height:40px; width:200px">Apply Promo</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are saving the promo data after applying but you can set a session for it and do like this:

```
  <form action="{{ url('/pay') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
            <h3>item1    price</h3>
            <h3>item1    price</h3>
@if(session()->has('promo'))
            <h3> Need to add new promo field dynamically after promo applied<h3>
@endif
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
            
        </form>
```